# How to find the median of a random variable given it's probability density function?

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function, median

Find the median of the random variable with the probability density function given below. (Round your answer to four decimal places.)
f(x) = 1/x on [1, e]

I do know that I am going to somehow use 1/2 but that is about it.

So for this problem I am not exactly sure where to start. We have had examples in our notes of finding the median but not with an equation like this one. I previously worked out a problem involving this on this website but I cannot figure out how to do this one. If someone could explain to me how to get to the answer it would be greatly appreciated. I know that I have to take the integral at some point but that is about it.

Comment: The median is the point that splits the density in half: half is smaller, and half is larger.

Comment: I do understand that part of it I'm just struggling with the rest of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve: $$\int_1^x \frac1t~dt=\frac12$$

Comment: @user344249 You have $\ln(x)=\frac12$ so $x=...$

Comment: OHHHHHH so it ends up being the square root of e, wow I feel dumb, thank you so much for the help I seriously appreciate it

Comment: @user344249 That's correct. Good job!

Comment: While I have you here how would i go about finding the expected value of the same equation

Comment: @user344249 Just compute $\int_1^e x \frac1x~dx$

Comment: Okay thank you again so much for the help!